# Organize shards with citus data when tenant_id of a record is updated

Tags: postgresql, sharding, citus

I want to use citus data to shard my postgres database. before jumping into it i want to fully understand its behaviour in different scenarios. Although the docs explain most of the cases.

I want to know how would I go about moving data to a different shard when i update `tenant_id` of a record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citus errors out when you try to update the value of the partition column. You can move the data with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` followed by a `DELETE FROM ...` inside a transaction.